# Supply an Arduino via the magnetic energy created by a mains wire?

Tags: power-supply, inductive

I'm a software developer trying out some electronics projects so this might be a stupid question but here it goes:

Is it possible to put a coil around the mains wire (220V/50Hz) that would be able to power a small Arduino circuit (5V/15mA) by induction only?

I've seen some power consumption monitoring devices that seem to be powered that way so I believe that such power supply is possible but I don't know what to search for in order to find eater schematics or complete circuit.

Comment: By mains wire do you mean a consumer grade cable, or just the phase/neutral of an installation? Will you guarantee there is current flowing or will there be no current flowing?

Comment: Short answer: No. The power consumption monitoring you might refer to most likley have a power consumption several orders of magnitude lower.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Yes it would be phase/neutral of an instalation, I'd need it to power the Arduino only while the current is flowing of course (i.e. appliance connected to that wire is running).

Comment: How much current is running? How big inductor can you allow around the cable? Snap on or disconnect the wire, thread it though the inductor and reconnect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, wrapping a coil around a straight wire does not make a transformer.

To derive electric power from a magnetic field, the field has to go "thru the hoop" of a coil of wire.  The magnetic field around a straight wire is circular around that wire.  If you wrap another wire around the first wire, that second wire is essentially following the magnetic field, not making a loop for it to go thru.

Answer (score 2):

Olin is correct about the geometry of the magnetic field created by a single straight wire such as you would like to use. The magnetic field around such a wire takes the shape of a cylinder which is co-axial to the wire. This cylinder is made up of an infinite number of circular magnetic flux tubes (the "magnetic field"). Picture these as thousands of orbits, or thin rings surrounding the axis of the wire, and in many diameters around  the wire. The magnetic flux in each ring is **inversely** proportional to its diameter (distance from the wire), and **directly** proportional to the current flowing thru the wire. So, the closer the individual ring to the wire and the stronger the current, the greater the magnetic flux ("magnetism") in that specific ring.

In order to convert this magnetic flux into another electric current ("induction") you must intercept as many of these rings as possible with a coil of wire. It helps if this coil has a magnetically conductive core such as iron or ferrite.

This is why a toroidal coil is generally used to pick up the flux from a wire for purposes of measuring its current flow in a non-contacting manner. I.e. the wire coil's turns are intersecting a maximum number of complete flux rings because it surrounds the wire completely. Plus, the toroid's ferrite core is acting as a conductor of the magnetic flux tubes that are being intersected, magnifying the strength of the captured magnetism.

Even though the toroidal geometry is the optimum geometry for capturing the maximum possible amount of magnetism produced by the current in the wire, there are other, less-than-optimum geometries. For example, you can wind a long thin rectangular coil and position it lengthwise along the wire (without making electrical contact with the current carrying wire). Or, you can make a toroidal coil with a gap thru which you can slip the current carrying wire without having to disconnect it, or un wire it to make the "connection".

Most important, you only want to pass one of the wires (either Neutral or Hot) thru the coil or alongside the coil. If you get the two current carrying wires too close to each other, their magnetic fields will cancel each other out and you will get a net magnetic field of zero, and no induced voltage in the coil.

Also, for the sake of safety you can perform all of these experiments with a low voltage AC source. For example, a 6 or 12 volt transformer connected to a resistive load sized to produce the same current the appliance would draw in your actual application. The voltage has no effect whatsoever on the voltage induced into the coil, only the current flowing thru the conductor you are measuring. Don't mess around with the mains until you have more experience. Another point, the current carrying conductor does not have to be bare to induce the voltage into the coil, leave the insulation on the mains wiring. Don't flirt with death!

Finally, the math behind all of this is very complicated. You will do much better as an untrained EE to determine the feasibility of your concept experimentally. Try various numbers of turns on the coil ( the more turns the higher the voltage, but the less power it can deliver to your load), and the dimensions of the coil which will best work & fit in your application. Once you have more experience with these and some experimental w=results to work with, you can ask more specific questions in this forum to help optimize your results.

Good Luck!